# Pasting a download link into Google Chrome for OS X

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts, safari

When I want to download something in Safari, like `http://foo.com/bar.zip`, all I have to do is paste that link into the *Downloads* window.  Is there a way to do this in Chrome?

I've gotten used to Safari, hitting ⌥⌘L (*Downloads* window), and then pasting.  It's quick, neat, and saves me from going to *File » Save As…*.

I like to keep my hands on the keyboard, so if there is a quick way to do this without using a mouse, that's my ideal solution.

Comment: Just [select and] drag the link to the tabs area. You can go to Options->Under the Hood->Downloads to change the folder and disable the File Save As

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I've edited my question above.

Comment: If you're open for other solutions, I'll look into making an Automator/AppleScript solution.

Comment: Ooooo, apple script.  I like where you're going there Beck.

Comment: Note you can paste a link into Firefox's downloads window to start a download. I just wish Chrome had this tiny feature too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `Automator`, it's quite easy to create a *Service* that downloads selected URLs.

Open *Automator*, create a *Service* that receives *URLs* as input in *any application*. Add the *Download URLs* action (don't worry about the Safari icon, the application isn't used at all or even started when executing). Save as "Download URL" or similar. You can now access the service from *Application menu » Services » Download URL*

Go to *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Services*, locate your new service, and assign a keyboard shortcut.

To use your service, select a URL and press the assigned keyboard shortcut. The file will appear in the folder specified in Automator.

---

You can optionally append the *Reveal Finder Items* Automator action. This would open your downloads folder after the file is saved, and select the downloaded file.

Comment: Wow, well done sir.  That is a great work around!

Comment: Again, I'd vote you up if I could.  I'll try using my mind again...

Comment: @fakeit Thanks anyway. You'll get there in time ;) Good question by the way, I've been bothered by a similar problem, but didn't care to solve it until now...

Comment: Well I appreciate your timely solution.  Now I can get on to listing to my buddy's new tunes.  All this, and I don't have to leave the keyboard!  Geekiness accomplished!

Answer (score 4):

Paste it into the URL bar and press `Return`. You can reach it using `Cmd-L`.

While Safari allows you to `Option-Return` to download any URL this way, Chrome does not support that, so `http://example.org/file.zip` will download, `http://example.org/file.htm` won't.

Comment: What about http://example.org/file.mp3?  Those are some of the more common files I'm downloading.  My friend wants me to check out his music, so I copy from chat and paste to the browser.  I'd love it to just drop into my downloads folder if possible.

Comment: @fakeit Same problem as with `htm`. Don't know if there's another way. You probably should edit your question to reflect that it's about files with viewing support in your browser.

Comment: Ah okay.  This is why I love safari's download window.  Handy little cheat :)

Comment: @fakeit As I wrote, in Safari, it's not even necessary. Just `Option-Return` the URL in the navigation bar and it'll download. Chrome seems to be missing both options though.

Comment: Very true.  I'm hooking you up with a +1 since, while you didn't solve the original problem, you made me an even geekier Safari user.  Well done.  --edit-- or at least I will when I hit 15 rep, it would seem :)

Comment: Ha ha!  I've hooked you up with a +1 using only my mind!

Answer (score 0):

Press **CMD + S** in the Chrome browser window where the URL is displaying and it should automatically download the URL :)

Comment: This is simply not working or you'll have to explain better. Where is the URL displaying in the first place? If I paste an URL to the address bar, pressing ⌘S won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new text document in a text editor (eg. notepad). Copy/paste the code below into the file, inserting your link. Save it as a .htm file (you may need to surround the new filename with quotes ie. save it as "downloader.htm"). Open it in your browser and right click-save as to download! Simples!

```
<HTML><BODY><A HREF="your_link_here">LINK!</a></BODY></HTML>
```

Cheers,

Rob

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer, but I'm putting it here for anybody who may still stumble upon this post as I just have.  If the previous answers do not suit your needs, you can do as follows:

> 1) In *Google Chrome*, **right click**  the element in which the file
>   you're interested is contained.
>
> 2) Select **"Inspect Element"** to quickly locate the section of HTML in
>   which the element is defined.
>
> 3) Locate the portion of the element tag in which the **"HREF"** or **"SRC"** is written and copy the URL contained within.

You now have a number of options:

> 4a) If you intend to save a video, music, or an image, you should be able
>   to **right click** the element and select the **"Save** [*file type*] **as..."** option in the drop down menu.
>
> 4b) Alternatively, for most filetypes, you can use an online
>   download tool by **copying and pasting the URL found in step 3** into
>   a form and simply hitting **"Enter"**, as is the case for the online
>   download tool, [File2HD.com](http://file2hd.com/).